# problem about css background image and fonts with hosting

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, path, host

i just recently finish to code my first website and i want to host it.
i succeed to upload it on webhost but i have a css problem.
on the local it looks like that
[website in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whRmd.jpg)

but on the website it looks like that
[website in hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV8Ol.png)

we can clearly see that only a part of the css works
the background image and the fonts is not working.

in the console network we can see that the link for the background-image link is not correct [here is a picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8crsP.png)

so the link in the console is /assets/css/img/1364.webp but it should be /assets/img/1364.webp

So the first think I did, is to check the link in the css

here is a part of the css code

```
body {
  background: url('../img/1364.webp') ;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

We can see the url begins with "../" so normally it should go back from one folder so go into the assets folder where you can find several stuff like img folder.
but it's not working at all.

this is how i organise the folder [picture of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPvBR.png)

i try a lot of things like :
change the path
change the background-image
...
but always the same problem.
I only talk about the background image but the font is the same error.
because i'm a beginner i am completly lost and i hope it was clear to understand
thanks

Comment: Try url('assets/img/1364.webp') for background and for css  assets/css/samplename.css.  I usually does like this on public < folder for css >, <another folderfor js> <another folder for images> etc.  then all pages are just below it not in a folder.

Comment: thanks for your answering i tried your version and it still not working the link became  assets/css//assets/img/1364.webp . It's really weird

Comment: where are you running this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible to use absolute path for you?
Using absolute path is a good habit to avoid such problem.

I saw you said the link becomes `/PATH/OF/CSS//your/specified/link` then it might be the configuration of your hosting solution, alternatively you can use url like `example.com/public_html/img/1364.webp`.

Comment: why did i  not think about absolute path lmao. Yeah it works thank you